# How to fix an issue with running a script in Atom?

Tags: atom-editor

I am trying to run a Python script in Atom but it is not working. I see an hourglass appear but no window pane to enter my inputs and run the code. What should I do?

I have already downloaded the Script package and have tried running the script but it does not seem to work yet.

Comment: The `script` package does not support input. You need to use a [REPL package](https://atom.io/packages/search?q=repl) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Please try :

1.Open your atom editor

2.Press the combination key ctrl+shift+p to enter the setting Enter or click the file menu to select setting

3.Select install click on the search box

4.Search for atom-python-run or script

5.The former (recommended) uses F5 to start the program, the latter is the combination key ctrl+shift+b

6.After the installation is complete, open the python document and press the corresponding key combination to see if the terminal has been opened.